# MicroMeter: remove/disable a certain tag

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I'm using the default MicroMeter binders, one of them creating the Gauage `jvm.memory.used`. The issue is that it comes with 2 availableTags: "area" and "id". This is practically generating 6 Gauges which I'm not interested in.

I was able to do this:

```
@Bean
public MeterRegistryCustomizer<MeterRegistry> metricsCustomizer() {

    return  registry -> {
        registry.config().meterFilter(MeterFilter.ignoreTags("id"));
    };
}
```

but this will ignore *all meters* with this tag.

How can I `deny()` only `jvm.memory.used` with an `id` tag?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Looking at the globalRegistry:

`Metrics.globalRegistry.getRegistries().iterator().next().meterMap`

Every `Meter` of `jvm.memory.used` is of the following structure:

`"MeterId{name='jvm.memory.used', tags=[tag(area=nonheap),tag(id=Metaspace)]}"`

So we can't just filter by `getName().equals("jvm.memory.used") && getTag("id") != null`

Comment: answer below has been updated and I tested it to be confirmed working locally

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you maybe conflating concepts.  The tags just "decorate" the metrics/gauges with additional information, they don't actually result in more gauges being sent.  For example, the line `Metrics.gauge("name", Tags.of("id","a", "area","b"), 1)` is just a single gauge object.  Denying `jvm.memory.used` with an `id` tag will probably deny all `jvm.memory.used`.  If you still want to filter `jvm.memory.used` with the `id` tag you can use

```
@Bean
public MeterFilter meterFilter() {
    return MeterFilter.deny(
        id -> "jvm.memory.used".equals(id.getName()) &&
              id.getTags().stream().anyMatch(t -> "id".equals(t.getKey()))
         );
    }
```

If on the other hand you just wanted to *remove* just the `id` tag, you will need to use the `replaceTags` method.

```
@Bean
public MeterFilter meterFilter() {
    return new MeterFilter() {
        @Override
        public Meter.Id map(Meter.Id id) {
            if("jvm.memory.used".equals(id.getName())) {
                List<Tag> tags = id.getTags().stream().filter(t -> !"id".equals(t.getKey())).collect(Collectors.toList());
                return id.replaceTags(tags);
            }
           return id;
        }
    };
}
```

You can also completely customize the `Meter.Id` returned by calling `new Meter.Id(name, tags, baseUnit, description, type)` as below, and chaning whichever values you want to:

```
@Bean
public MeterFilter meterFilter() {
    return new MeterFilter() {
        @Override
        public Meter.Id map(Meter.Id id) {
            if("jvm.memory.used".equals(id.getName())) {
                return new Meter.Id(id.getName(), <put tags here>, id.getBaseUnit(), id.getDescription(), id.getType()
            }
           return id;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I'll give it a shot tomorrow, thanks in the meantime!

Comment: So sadly both methods doesn't work - The first one can't be done since the tags are immutable and the second one removes all "jvm.memory.used" meters.

Comment: I added an explanation in my question

Comment: @yaseco sorry I missed your response, I didn't get a notification.  Removed the `removeIf` since it did not work and added something else which should do what you are looking for.

Comment: Works like a charm - Sorry for the late response and thanks a lot!

Comment: can something like this be done for webclient ? where I want to filter all requests going to one particular endpoint from my application .